# Shared global event between a service & user-mode processes doesn't work

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, synchronization, ipc

I'm trying to create a named global event that could be shared among my service and user process(-es). The user process may run under credentials of any low privileged logged in Windows user (even a built-in guest.) There's also no way of knowing which process will create this event first, i.e. service or a user process.

So from both the service & user-mode process the event is created/opened as such:

```
//Event name is made up using special/shared file path, and basically becomes something like this
strEventName = L"Global\\sa_evt_C:_Users_Name_C++_Mod0110_debug_TmLog0";

//Create descriptor for "ALL access"
PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR psdAll;
if(::ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptor(
    isWindowsVistaOrLater ? L"D:(A;;GA;;;WD)(A;;GA;;;AN)S:(ML;;;;;S-1-16-0)" : L"D:(A;;GA;;;WD)(A;;GA;;;AN)",
    SDDL_REVISION_1, &psdAll, NULL))
{
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;
    sa.nLength = sizeof(sa);
    sa.bInheritHandle = FALSE;
    sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = psdAll;

    hEvent = ::CreateEvent(&sa, TRUE, FALSE, strEventName);

    LocalFree(psdAll);
}
```

The issue I'm experiencing is that the event is created by both the service and user mode process(-es) but it's almost like if they each create their own (non-shared) copies of the event, i.e. when I signal it the other module does not see it (via WaitForSingleObject API.)

I also ran it through the debugger and, say, after this event is created in the service, I would expect the CreateEvent() API in the user process to succeed and return GetLastError as `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS`, but it returns `NO_ERROR`.

Any idea what am I doing wrong here and how to make it work?

Answer (score 3):

Fixed it. Silly mistake. Forgot that those kernel object names are case sensitive. What I should've done is called [CharLower](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647467%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)() on the part of the name that follows `Global\` to make it all lower case, and then it would've worked just fine.

As for the length of the kernel object name and characters allowed in it, there're basically two restrictions that I know of:

1. The part of the name that follows `Global\` (or `Local\`, or `Session\`) may contain any characters, except slashes, i.e. `\` or `/`.
2. And the full object name itself cannot exceed `MAX_PATH` characters (which is 260.) So it can be quite long.

Comment: Right except the object name is not limited to `MAX_PATH`. The object manager uses [`UNICODE_STRING`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff564879) names, which can handle paths up to 32768 characters long. Also, if you wanted this to be case insensitive you'd have to bypass the Windows API to call [`NtCreateEvent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff566423) directly with an [`ObjectAttributes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff557749) flagged as `OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE`.

Comment: @eryksun: I'm calling it from a user-mode process and not kernel driver. I'm taking the length restriction from here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682396%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: That limit applies to `CreateEventA` since the base uses a fixed-size static buffer to decode from ANSI to Unicode. It doesn't apply to `CreateEventW`. As to `ntdll!NtCreateEvent`, in case you don't know that's the system call underlying `CreateEvent`. Microsoft doesn't support directly making system calls from user mode; I was just saying that this would be the only way to make it case insensitive.

Answer (score 2):

> So from both the service & user-mode process the event is created/opened as such

There is an easier way to create a security descriptor that allows unrestricted access to the event:

```
SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR sd;
InitializeSecurityDescriptor(&sd, SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_REVISION);
SetSecurityDescriptorDacl(&sd, TRUE, NULL, FALSE);

SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa = {0};
sa.nLength = sizeof(sa);
sa.bInheritHandle = FALSE;
sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = &sd;

hEvent = ::CreateEvent(&sa, TRUE, FALSE, strEventName);
```

> There's also no way of knowing which process will create this event first, i.e. service or a user process.

You could require the user processes to use `OpenEvent()` instead of `CreateEvent()`. If the service is not running yet, the event would not be available to the processes.  Non-admin/elevated processes should not be **creating** objects in the `Global\` namespace, only *consuming* them, as they do not have the `SeCreateGlobalPrivilege` permission by default.

Comment: OK. So if I a low privileged user module creates this shared event first, if I don't use `Global\` how would the service have access to it then?

Comment: Also in my tests the event was created first by the service, but the user mode still didn't seem to see it. Any idea why?

Comment: You cannot share a named kernel object across session boundaries without the use of the `Global` namespace, that is why it exists in the first place. Remember that in Vista and later, services run in a dedicated session, never in user sessions (like they could in XP and earlier). Also, try using a simpler object name, such as a guid. Maybe your use of colons and underscores is causing lookup issues.

Comment: I think I got it. Forgot that those names are case-sensitive. Thanks for your input. Oh, and concerning your "easier way." I'm not really a big fan of NULL DACLs. I'm more restrictive in my security selector.

Comment: `SeCreateGlobalPrivilege` is required to create a file mapping (i.e. a `Section` object) in the global namespace. Another restriction is `DefineDosDevice` can only create a global DOS device when called from a `LocalSystem` context. But there's no such restriction on creating global named events.

Answer (score -1):

```
InitializeSecurityDescriptor(&sd, SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_REVISION);
SetSecurityDescriptorDacl(&sd, TRUE, NULL, FALSE);
```

Which I used to sync between IE activeX and native app, but it again failed. then i switched to `ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptor`, it works well.